# TFS API VS2010 - How do I set the comment on a workitem revision?

Tags: tfs-sdk, tfs-workitem, revisions

I've been beating my head against the wall and can't figure this out. I would post an image to help show you what I mean, but I'm a newbie ;)

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Can you edit your question and tell us what you are trying to do in a bit more detail?

Answer (score 0):

You can't revise a comment on a changeset once it has been committed.